# Laravel 9.x html form action cannot find view blade file

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a simple login page but I cannot reach my action page on html, I'm not sure about the syntax. I have a function that stores data from the input form but I can't even view the form and laravel shows an error that says this -> ["Action message not defined."].

Here is my code and the error I get;
[This Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ2y6.png)

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/message',[App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::class,'getData']);
Route::view('login','message');
```

**PagesController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function getData(Request $Req)
    {
        return $Req->input();
    }
}
```

**message.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{action ('message')}}" method="POST">
@csrf
```

Comment: `action ('message')` You don't have the name on the route defined.

Comment: @aynber how can I do this could you send the docs or tell me exactly where to put it thanks in advance

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#named-routes

Comment: @aynber would you like to answer the question? So that way I can learn better. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the route name, you need to actually name the route:

```
Route::post('/message',[App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::class,'getData'])->name('message');
```

And you'll need to change `action` to `route`

```
<form action="{{route('message')}}" method="POST">
```

Comment: I tried it but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: ... and change the form action to `{{route('message')}}`

Comment: Thank you so much both of you. I respect you guys so much.  That one fixed my problem.